# dictionary generation using list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to generate the result from given JSON data and it's generating some partial result. The JSON data is preformatted to understand and dictionary consist of key-value pair most of it. My code is running and but don't understand how to get a particular value to print from the dictionary.

Given JSON data :

```
{
"aggregates": [{
        "services_count": 9,
        "service_name": "S3",
        "business_unit": "IT OPS",
        "last_month_costs": 0,
        "total_cost": 0.3200019691,
        "ytd_spends": 0.3200019691,
        "account_id": "136981853693"
    },
    {
        "services_count": 5,
        "service_name": "RDS",
        "business_unit": "Customer Service",
        "last_month_costs": 0,
        "total_cost": 297.6462777693,
        "ytd_spends": 297.6462777693,
        "account_id": "136981853693"
    },
    {
        "services_count": 38,
        "service_name": "EBS",
        "business_unit": "IT OPS",
        "last_month_costs": 0,
        "total_cost": 49.7080945265006,
        "ytd_spends": 49.7080945265006,
        "account_id": "136981853693"
    },
    {
        "services_count": 3,
        "service_name": "ELB",
        "business_unit": "IT OPS",
        "last_month_costs": 0,
        "total_cost": 1.5519276537,
        "ytd_spends": 1.5519276537,
        "account_id": "136981853693"
    },
    {
        "services_count": 22,
        "service_name": "EC2",
        "business_unit": "IT OPS",
        "last_month_costs": 0,
        "total_cost": 442.70678455851,
        "ytd_spends": 442.70678455851,
        "account_id": "136981853678"
    }
]
}
```

My code is: Note -  at the beginning of the program pass row = JSON data as it is.

```
from itertools import groupby

def format_account_details(rows):
  result = {}
  total_accounts = 0
  total_account_cost = 0


  for k,v in groupby(rows,key=lambda x:x["account_id"]):
    result[k] = {}
    for k2,v2 in groupby(v,key=lambda x:x["business_unit"]):
      result[k][k2] = list(v2)
      for k3 in result[k][k2]:
        total_account_cost = total_account_cost + k3['total_cost']

  resp = []
  resp.append('total_accounts:{}'.format(len(result.keys())))
  resp.append('total_cost:{}'.format(total_account_cost))

  for k,v in result.items():
    for k2,v2 in v.items():
        resp.append({'account_id':k,'business_unit':k2,'top_utilized':v2})
  return resp
  result.update(resp)
  print(result)
print(format_account_details(row["aggregates"]))
```

My Result is as follows:

```
['total_accounts:2',
'total_cost:791.9330864771106',
{
    'account_id': '136981853693',
    'business_unit': 'IT OPS',
    'top_utilized': [{
            'services_count': 38,
            'service_name': 'EBS',
            'business_unit': 'IT OPS',
            'last_month_costs': 0,
            'total_cost': 49.7080945265006,
            'ytd_spends': 49.7080945265006,
            'account_id': '136981853693'
        },
        {
            'services_count': 3,
            'service_name': 'ELB',
            'business_unit': 'IT OPS',
            'last_month_costs': 0,
            'total_cost': 1.5519276537,
            'ytd_spends': 1.5519276537,
            'account_id': '136981853693'
        }
    ]
}

,
{
    'account_id': '136981853693',
    'business_unit': 'Customer Service',
    'top_utilized': [{
        'services_count': 5,
        'service_name': 'RDS',
        'business_unit': 'Customer Service',
        'last_month_costs': 0,
        'total_cost': 297.6462777693,
        'ytd_spends': 297.6462777693,
        'account_id': '136981853693'
    }]
}

,
{
    'account_id': '136981853678',
    'business_unit': 'IT OPS',
    'top_utilized': [{
        'services_count': 22,
        'service_name': 'EC2',
        'business_unit': 'IT OPS',
        'last_month_costs': 0,
        'total_cost': 442.70678455851,
        'ytd_spends': 442.70678455851,
        'account_id': '136981853678'
    }]
}

]
```

Expected Result is :

```
{
"total_accounts": 123,
"total_cost_accounts": 325467,
"aggregates": [{
    "accounts_number": 345465767,
    "business_unit": "Customer Service",
    "services_count": 22,
    "payeer_id": 43454575,
    "last_month_spend": 8434,
    "ytd_spend": 76767,
    "forecast_spend": 8322,
    "top_utilized": [{
        "service_name": "EC2",
        "usage": "500 hours",
        "cost": 435
    }, {
        "service_name": "Route 53",
        "usage": "10 domains",
        "cost": 415
    }, {
        "service_name": "S3",
        "usage": "50 TB",
        "cost": 310
    }, {
        "service_name": "OTHERS",
        "usage": "50 TB",
        "cost": 310
    }]
}, {
    "accounts_number": 7895465767,
    "business_unit": "Customer Service",
    "services_count": 8,
    "payeer_id": 789454575,
    "last_month_spend": 3234,
    "ytd_spend": 42767,
    "forecast_spend": 3322,
    "top_utilized": [{
        "service_name": "EC2",
        "usage": "500 hours",
        "cost": 335
    }, {
        "service_name": "Lamda",
        "usage": "1M REQUESTS",
        "cost": 315
    }, {
        "service_name": "EBS",
        "usage": "500 GB",
        "cost": 210
    }]
}]
}
```

Need suggestions. Thank you

Comment: If you import `operator`, then `key=lambda x:x["account_id"]` can be written `key=operator.itemgetter("account_id")`.

Comment: @PaulMcG Thank you for your help, but still, I am not getting the expected result.